# Update a TextBox from another thread in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to update a `TextBox` from another thread in a WPF application. Normally, in WinForms, I would use `InvokeRequired`, but that is not available here now. When looking around I found this solution:

```
class SomeClass {
      private textBox_Log;
      public SomeClass(TextBox tb) {
           textBox_Log = tb;
      }

      public Log(string m) {
           Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
               textBox_Log.Text += m + "\n";
           });
      }
}
```

but that complains about the `Dispatcher` not being available.

How can I update that `TextBox` from another thread (to be precise, the call originates from an event handler triggered in a `FileSystemWatcher`).

Comment: Try to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` or `Dispatcher` of specific window/control, like `tb.Dispatcher`

Comment: Yes, thanks. Too bad that one doesn't show up in the Google searches :)

Comment: Well, it was a first result from google search query:)

Comment: @BartFriederichs, have you considered using `async-await`